# AWS S3 Bucket Policy Allow Access From Certain URL’s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi

I have a power bi app that stores pdfs in an s3 bucket.  I wish to only allow access to the documents when requested from the power bi web app or the web app embeded in a web page I administer (beyondmapping.com).  I have used the policy generator to create the following bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1513783148229",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1513783134644",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::flsarchives/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://app.powerbi.com/*",
                        "https://www.app.powerbi.com/*",
                        "http://beyondmapping.com/*",
                        "http://www.beyondmapping.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy validates and AWS warns me 'This bucket has public access', but when I try to access via https://app.powerbi.com/ I get...

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>3FC57FCB880F8210</RequestId>
<HostId>
5MSm6vqLs12IgCNdVXj9p+GTg/aMxQ2U/FJ1PBPWX9vypn+OIPmzpBOpSZx1y3KkGhIz9MoTraQ=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

What should I do differently or additionally to retrieve documents from these urls?

Edit: Current CORS.  Not sure if this is related and not sure what it should look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.appdomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Have you enabled [CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors) ?

Comment: Ive left alone.  How should I do this?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

Comment: The docs dont say much.  I have adjusted to exactly reflect cors example in the docs.

Comment: @NoahHuntington What happens if you use http instead of https in the aws:Referer?

Comment: @sudo Same results. 'Access Denied' :(

Comment: @NoahHuntingtonThanks for trying, just avoid that we are not missing anything obvious, could you please make sure that the request includes the "Referrer" element?

Comment: @sudo.  Please excuse my ignorance.  I'm not sure what this means.  Current policy states... "aws:Referer":...

Comment: @NoahHuntingtonSorry, I had a typo in there. As per my understanding, the aws:Referer condition key of IAM/Bucket policy is to compare with the referer header of the HTTP(S) request. So, if the request does not include the referer header, it should be denied, but, I'm not sure how to verify that :(

Comment: Thanks @sudo If the URIs in the aws:referer are incorrect in the header I am not sure how to check this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what was done differently, but I wound up installing [S3Browser](https://s3browser.com/) which allowed me to create and apply the following bucket policy.  The only difference I see is the  *"Action": "s3:GetObject"* policy.  It seemed to do the trick.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "preventHotLinking",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::flsarchives/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "https://app.powerbi.com/*",
            "https://www.app.powerbi.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I copied your answer, changed the bucket name and referrer links and it works perfectly, without installing anything else.